# Trying to reverse engineer teamviewer's printer driver

Tags: windows, binary-analysis, file-format, driver

Unlike `LogMeIn` or `GoToMyPC`, `TeamViewer` does not have any driver files except for the `INF and GPD` files. `LogMeIn` and `GoToMyPC` have their own configuration and driver dlls, while TeamViewer uses the `default unidrvui.dll for config and unidrv.dll as driver file`.

I don't seem to understand how Teamviewer is able to develop a `virtual printer driver` without writing their own driver dll.

VNC also seems to follow similar way, they use `unidrvui.dll and unidrv.dll`, but they have one more custom dll `VNCui.dll` (guess this is also a config dll).

Have anyone tried to reverse engineer `TeamViewer` or `VNC's` virtual printer driver? Please shed some light on this.

Comment: I may be missing some background knowledge but I can't really follow this question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [unidrv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unidrv) does not require any extra DLLs but just a [.GPD file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/hardware/drivers/print/introduction-to-gpd-files).

Looks like you need to analyze the GPD file to figure out how it all works.